# Image Video Thumbnail creating using PHP-FFmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am using [PHP-FFmpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg) for video thumbnail genaration. My code is below

```
<?php

$video = "a.mp4";
$image = "thumb.jpg";
$frame = $video->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(42));
$frame->save($image);
?>
```

I am trying above code to generate video thumbnail
it is showing

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function frame() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\video-uploader\ImageGenerator.php on line 5
```

Answer (score 3):

`$video` is a string, so you cannot access the method `frame()`.

You want:

```php
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
$video = $ffmpeg->open("a.mp4");
```

See the [basic usage](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg#basic-usage) example.

Comment: new code is  `$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
                    $video = $ffmpeg->open("a.mp4");
                    $video
                            ->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(10))
                            ->save('frame.jpg');`                                                                                  Which file to include here

Comment: What do you mean with "which file to include"?

Comment: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'FFMpeg\FFMpeg' not found

Comment: I can't help you with that. Have you followed the guide that I linked to? You should update your existing question with the complete code you're using.

Answer (score 0):

If it is to display on browser,
You can use HTML5 Video, this will generate a thumbnail from video at 4 seconds.

```
  <video  width="400" height="300" controls id="videopreview" preload="metadata"  >
    <source src="uploads/video_name.mp4#t=4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```